# Help in this exercise about Richardson extrapolation.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, extrapolation

We know $F(h)=a_0 +a_1h + a_2 h^3$

$F(1)=4$;  $F(1/2)=21/8$;  $F(1/4)=145/64$

Find a approximation of $F(0)=a_0$ with Richardson extrapolation method with an absolute error less than $10^{-2}.$

This is what I have done:
In Richardson method, we usually used this fact:

$$F(h)=a_0 +a_1h + a_2 h^3$$ then

$$F(h/2)=a_0 +a_1 \frac{h}{2} + a_2 \frac{h^3}{2^3}$$

So $$F(h)-F(h/2)=\frac{1}{2}a_1 h + \frac{7}{8}a_2h^3$$

Then we have this:

$$\frac{F(h)-F(h/2)}{F(h)-a_0}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}a_1 h +\frac{7}{8}a_2 h^3}{a_1 h+ a_2 h^3}$$

So we are asking  for getting $|F(h)-a_0|\leq 10^{-2}$ what $h$ we must take?

Thank you!

Original problem in Spanish:

[image: Original problem]

Comment: Can we use F(1) F(1/2) and F(1/4) with F(h) to get a system of 3 incognito ($a_0$ $a_1$ and $a_2$) and 3 equations for knowing $a_i$ and once we know $a_i$ see for what $h$ we have $|F(h)-a_0|\leq 10^{-2}$?  I think we cannot do this, please tell me if this way is allowed and if not  help for solve the question, thank you !

Comment: I think $F(1)$ $F(1/2)$ and $F(1/4)$ must used for computing $F_2(1/2)$, $F_2(1/4)$ and $F_3(1/4)$

Comment: Yes  , this is the entire problem, normally in Richardson extrapolation problems we have $F(h)=a_0+a_1 h^{p_1}+ a_2 h^{p_2}...$ and theoretically we know $F(h)-a_0\approx \frac{F(h)-F(h/2)}{1-\frac{1}{2^{p_1}}}$. But in this case we want to know exact value in order to give a bound for the error  .

Comment: I attached the original problem in Spanish, help please!

Comment: You may be interested in a proposal for Math SE in Spanish:http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64529/matematicas-mathematics-se-in-spanish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given form of $F(h)=a_0+a_1 h+a_2 h^3$, as you say, you can solve the system

$$F(1)=4,F(\tfrac{1}{2})=\tfrac{21}{8},F(\tfrac{1}{4})=\tfrac{145}{64}$$

for the coefficients, and obtain $(a_0,a_1,a_2)=(2,1,1)$, hence

$$F(h)=2+h+h^3.$$

For $h\geq 0$ the condition $\epsilon=|F(h)-F(0)|$ becomes a third-order equation in $h$,

$$h^3+h-\epsilon=0,$$

which can be solved using standard techniques. The only real solution is

$$h_{crit}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3^3 \epsilon^2+4}}{2\sqrt{3^3}}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)^{1/3}-\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3^3 \epsilon^2+4}}{2\sqrt{3^3}}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)^{-1/3}$$

For you tolerance of $\epsilon=10^{-2}$ this is

$$h<h_{crit}\approx 0.0099990003.$$